# Como atualizar um jogo unity

Tags: servidor, unity3d

Eu tenho um jogo publicado no GooglePlay, esse jogo só tem uma cena (menu), e os dados restantes do jogo estão em meu servidor. Como posso atualizar meu jogo (cena do menu), com mais dados de jogos do meu servidor, e este dados do jogo (compilação das outras cenas) ficar no mesmo jogo que foi transferido a partir GooglePlay(cena do menu)?

Comment: Seu servidor está rodando localmente?

Comment: Sim ele esta rodando localmente!

Comment: Olá. Eu não sei se eu entendi corretamente. A cena de menu é a única literalmente programada no aplicativo do jogo, sendo que o resto ele faz download do seu servidor toda vez que o jogo é aberto? A sua pergunta então seria como atualizar a cena de menu (ou seja, como atualizar o aplicativo do jogo no dispositivo móvel)?

Comment: Olá. Correto, a cena do menu é a única programada. A única diferença do que você citou, é que se o usuário clicar para baixar o outro pacote, o usuário não precisará baixa-lo de novo, quanto entrar novamente no jogo. A minha questão não seria somente como atualizar o jogo. Talvez um exemplo que posso ajudar a entender, é o jogo tipo angry birds, que possui varias fazes e quando eles vão lançando novas, aparece a opção para você baixa-las, sem que você precise baixar o jogo todo novamente. Espero que tenha ajudado a compreender minha dúvida.